# (!) Notice: Use of undefined constant nombre - assumed 'nombre'

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta a mi base de datos con php pero me arroja un error. Este e mi codigo

```
    [![<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "venividivici2016";
$password = "4XDjhDFsxBtbxRsw";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {



}



echo '<br/>';

$bd_seleccionada = mysqli_select_db($conn,"veniviajes");
if (!$bd_seleccionada) {
     die("Conecion fallida: " . mysqli_error($conn));
} else {



}

$sentencia= " SELECT nombre FROM pais";
  if(!$sentencia) 
    die("Error: no se pudo realizar la consulta");
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sentencia); 
 if(!$resultado) 
    die("Error: no se pudo realizar la consulta");



?>

<select>

<option value="">Seleccione</option>

<?php

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

?>

<option value="<?php echo $fila\[nombre\]; ?></option>

<?php } ?>

</select>]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

Prueba a imprimir el resultado con:

```
$fila["nombre"]
```

Prueba con este código, que a mi me ha funcionado:

```
            <?php 
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "venividivici2016";
        $password = "4XDjhDFsxBtbxRsw";

        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        $bd_seleccionada = mysqli_select_db($conn,"veniviajes");

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

            $sentencia = "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios";

            if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sentencia)) {

        ?>

                <br>
        <select>
            <option value="">Seleccione</option>

            <?php while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></option>

            <?php } ?>

        </select>
```

Comment: echo $fila["nombre"];   Notice: Undefined variable: fila in C:\wamp\www\php\conexionmysql.php

Comment: Tampoco muestras nada en el desplegable <option value="<?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></option>

Comment: @josejaviersegura  No me muestra nada en blanco despliega como si mostrará algo pero en blanco

Answer (score 3):

Cambia esta fila:

```
<option value="<?php echo $fila\[nombre\]; ?></option>
```

a

```
<option value="<?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>"></option>
```

A parte de no concatenar bien `$fila\[nombre\]` haz olvidado también de cerrar bien el `<option>` tag.

---

**Contestacíon actualizado según los comentarios:**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "venividivici2016";
$password = "4XDjhDFsxBtbxRsw";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
$bd_seleccionada = mysqli_select_db($conn,"veniviajes");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

    $sentencia = "SELECT nombre FROM pais";

    if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sentencia)) {

?>
<select>
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>

    <?php while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>"></option>

    <?php } ?>

</select>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <p>Comprobación: </p>
        <br>
        <p>Connexion: </p>
        <?php var_dump($conn); ?>
        <br>
        <p>Tabla seleccionado: </p>
        <?php var_dump($bd_seleccionada); ?>
        <br>
        <p>Resultado: </p>
        <?php var_dump($resultado); ?>
        <br>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41692/discussion-on-answer-by-aldanux-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-nombre-a).